# Google cloud storage object - Service account does not have storage object get access

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-vault-api

I have a service account for my GCP project that uses the Vault and Google Cloud Storage APIs. I have ensured that both of these APIs are enabled. I have also ensured my service account has the correct roles ( which have the permissions inherited ? ) for modifying storage objects ( I am downloading Exports from vault to my local server for archiving, which requires the get access / write permissions ) Storage Admin and Storage Object Admin. Do I have to generate a new service account Json Key if I modified the roles/permissions of the SA account after creation in order for the credentials to be updated in the API calls from the client or will they be updated with the same original SA key I made and continue to reference in the method api calls to get cloud storage objects ? Or am I simply not using SA credentials correctly for these APIs ?

[IAM service account showing roles/permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e6n1.png)

[Cloud Storage API showing enabled and service account credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEL2c.png)

For clarity, this is what an export data object contains:

```
{'exports': [{'id': 'v3_MAIL_241a6eba-d2b3-45b1-83fd-fd343b3cf750', 'matterId': '4bbc1e6e-85c2-467e-b967-1c0e83ed90e4', 'name': 'test export', 'requester': {'email': 'a.richardson@striveworks.us', 'displayName': 'Alexi Richardson'}, 'query': {'corpus': 'MAIL', 'dataScope': 'ALL_DATA', 'searchMethod': 'ACCOUNT', 'accountInfo': {'emails': ['a.richardson@striveworks.us']}, 'mailOptions': {}, 'timeZone': 'America/Chicago', 'method': 'ACCOUNT'}, 'exportOptions': {'mailOptions': {'exportFormat': 'MBOX', 'showConfidentialModeContent': True, 'useNewExport': True}, 'region': 'US'}, 'createTime': '2022-05-05T21:17:37.695Z', 'status': 'COMPLETED', 'stats': {'exportedArtifactCount': '20856', 'totalArtifactCount': '20856', 'sizeInBytes': '1133035820'}, 'cloudStorageSink': {'files': [{'bucketName': '9b750b66-7789-466d-9ad4-c41c78529347', 'objectName': '50284674:4bbc1e6e-85c2-467e-b967-1c0e83ed90e4:v3_MAIL_241a6eba-d2b3-45b1-83fd-fd343b3cf750/a830db3a-8317-4fba-ad20-9d70415f67d6', 'size': '1126473769', 'md5Hash': 'b7c144cd03255b217b5ab6dd2a6c37c2'}, {'bucketName': '9b750b66-7789-466d-9ad4-c41c78529347', 'objectName': '50284674:4bbc1e6e-85c2-467e-b967-1c0e83ed90e4:v3_MAIL_241a6eba-d2b3-45b1-83fd-fd343b3cf750/686a456b-d796-439a-8ef3-beac4e071826', 'size': '6561479', 'md5Hash': '63cd3eac2c7cb41699c4e6b908cff72a'}, {'bucketName': '9b750b66-7789-466d-9ad4-c41c78529347', 'objectName': '50284674:4bbc1e6e-85c2-467e-b967-1c0e83ed90e4:v3_MAIL_241a6eba-d2b3-45b1-83fd-fd343b3cf750/5cc3e164-9758-4d39-9f71-2c3d0ad8555f', 'size': '442', 'md5Hash': '75e7e6081ab433267ec1513c39970d3f'}, {'bucketName': '9b750b66-7789-466d-9ad4-c41c78529347', 'objectName': '50284674:4bbc1e6e-85c2-467e-b967-1c0e83ed90e4:v3_MAIL_241a6eba-d2b3-45b1-83fd-fd343b3cf750/343f5811-83a7-4165-814f-18a8cbb1649e', 'size': '130', 'md5Hash': '12746dd0443dd4fc1a2968b5866b2d6b'}]}}]}
```

I am invoking the SA key credentials explicitly in the function like this at the `storage_client` line:

```
#METHOD 1 for downloading exports
def download_exports_primary(service, matter_id):
 #""" Google Cloud storage service is authenticated by running `gcloud auth application-default login`
#    and expects a billing enabled project in ENV variable `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` """

    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('/opt/gws/creds/gws-vault-data-export-ops-bfd51297e810.json')

    for export in service.matters().exports().list(matterId=matter_id).execute()['exports']:
      if 'cloudStorageSink' in export:
        directory = export['name']
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
          os.makedirs(directory)
        print('\n')
        print(export['id'])
        for sinkFile in export['cloudStorageSink']['files']:
            filename = '%s/%s' % (directory, sinkFile['objectName'].split('/')[-1])
            objectURI = 'gs://%s/%s' % (sinkFile['bucketName'],sinkFile['objectName'])
            print('\n')
            print('Pulling export download....')
            print('\n')
            print('get %s to %s' % (objectURI, filename))
            print('\n')
            #storage_client.download_blob_to_file(objectURI, open(filename, 'wb+'))
            try:
                with open(filename, 'wb') as outfile:
                    storage_client.download_blob_to_file(objectURI, outfile)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            else:
                print('No exception')
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/9b750b66-7789-466d-9ad4-c41c78529347/o/a5b3ae10-2e47-4a03-9b4d-4856c9f13356%2Fexportly-00b683d9-807c-41f8-b9fd-c1e82281ba9d%2Fj.howell%40striveworks.usGMAIL_EXPORT-1.zip?alt=media: gws-vault-sac@gws-vault-data-export-ops.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.: ('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)
```

Comment: 1) IAM roles are not inherited. 2) If you change the roles assigned to a service account, you do **not** need to redownload it. 3) My guess is that you have incorrectly specified the bucket name.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am not specifying the bucket name per se, it is just getting the bucket name from the provided cloud storage sink data that gets generated when I make an export automatically because it also makes a bucket with some rando char id string. So it is getting the matter id then finding the associated export, then pulling the bucket name from a dictionary key that the export contents resides in. I think I am just going to completely erase the SA profile and make a new one.

Comment: Is the bucket in the same project as the service account? If not, you will need to add the service account and IAM roles to the project that owns the bucket.

Comment: It seems futile via the API. When you make an export in Vault there is a bucket that is auto created in the backend that holds the data for ~15 days and then it deletes it so you have to download it. I do not have access and cannot get access to this bucket because it already exists with some random string name and is auto-ephemeral borrowed temp storage so to speak. So to answer your question, my GCP project has this SA that that has buckets that I created for uploading data, but it does not have this bucket that holds the exported data I am trying to download. I have to authen differently?

Comment: I do not understand your comment.

Comment: It is okay, turns out someone else had this problem and the solution is that the bucket is not accessible in an export, only the objects inside the bucket are accessible. So I will just work on getting the actual objects in the export bucket and not the containing bucket itself.